# Search by category in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to load all category names in an array after that check the input search field with array if found then go to that category page . How to get this done?

Comment: Even if this question is too broad to be answered I'm going to give you a hint. The thing you are looking for is called *autocomplete* and there are already free/paid extensions to implement such functionality into OpenCart. The other thing is that you do not want to load all the categories prior to search itself is done, but to use the searched keyword and try to find all the categories that match that keyword - so the matching is done by MySQL and only matching records are returned - this lowers the resources needed to fullfill your search request.

Answer (score 0):

1) make one function in catalog\model\catalog\product.php,it will return all active category

2) load this function at catalog\controller\product\search.php at line 17

3) use in_array function to get result,searched title is in or not

4) redirection code if searched title is in category array

Thanks